# Firebase hosting case-sensitive works in local but not when hosted

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am using Firebase Hosting. Hosting it in local for testing via command

```
firebase serve --only hosting
```

This hosts all files fine irrespective of the case mismatch in the urls.

Once this is Hosted onto Firebase, all the case-sensitive links are broken. 
I know Firebase is case-sensitive, but how does it work in local hosting?

This would make no sense of local testing if it fails after Hosting on to cloud.

Comment: is this true also for `firebase emulators:start --only hosting`?  I ask because `firebase serve` is being deprecated, so maybe `emulators` has fixed this?  If not, you might open an issue here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with Windows or a Macos filesystem that isn't case sensitive, then the emulator probably isn't going to discern between FOO.HTML and foo.html, since the operating system thinks they're essentially the same. **Your code should always respect case, regardless of what system is hosting it - Firebase Hosting in production requires it.**

Comment: true, code should be in sync with cases. But was curious to know what caused it to not fail. Turns out its at OS level. Thank you for the info.